# firebase notification showing in textview while apps in foreground but while i click on notification message not showing in textview android

Tags: android

i want to show fcm notification message in textview and i can show while apps in foreground. but while apps is closed it is not showing in textview. can anyone please help me.

my codes:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());



//            Intent intent=new Intent();
//            intent.putExtra("MSG",remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
//            intent.setAction("imran");
//            sendBroadcast(intent);

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

    }

private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("FireBaseNotification",messageBody);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_email_24dp)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent.setAction("imran"));
    }
```

Broadcastreceiver:

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            TextView fcmTv;
            fcmTv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.button);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),intent.getStringExtra("FireBaseNotification"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            fcmTv.setText(intent.getStringExtra("FireBaseNotification"));
            Log.v("jksdfh",intent.getStringExtra("FireBaseNotification"));

        }
    };
```

is ithere any other way without storing message ?

Comment: show me your onMessageReceived() method

Comment: use like this.  remoteMessage.getData().get("your_key_name"); you should specified your body name.

Comment: where to edit this(may be your solution not working)? i am getting the message body and showing successfully while apps is in foreground but not while apps is closed.

Comment: that meant your local brodacast manager not broadcasting when your app is close.. now use getIntent in your mainActivity's onCreate. wait i m writing answer here.

Comment: ok please and thanks

Answer (score 0):

write this code in your mainActivity's onCreate method: if your notification intent has data than print in your textview while click on notification.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
              String msg = bundle.getString("FireBaseNotification");
              fcmTv.setText(msg));
            }
```

Comment: but as i am broadcasting from onMessageReceived then how will i  get it from oncreate in activity?

Comment: no need for broadcasting, your notification intent opening mainActivity, so you just need to get data using getIntent().

Comment: it works if your intent really has data..  so make sure this log is  get data or not.   Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

Comment: it is only working only when apps is open but i wanted to show while apps is closed

Answer (score 0):

When onMessageReceived() method is triggered store the data received in local storage ([Shared Preference](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)) and in onCreate() method set the text using the value stored in sharedPreference. If you dont want to store it in local storage, declare a static variable

```
public static fcm_to_text = "";
```

set value of that variable in onMessageReceived() and in onCreate() method set text of textview using fcm_to_text variable.

--------------------------------------------------------EDITED----------------------------------------------------------------
MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        SharedPreferences test = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = test.edit();
        editor.putString("testing",remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        editor.commit();
        Log.e("messageData",remoteMessage.getData().toString());

    } 
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        SharedPreferences data = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile",0);
        Log.e("main",data.getString("testing","novalue"));
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i tried with preference but it does not show if i click on notification while apps is closed

Comment: can you update your MainActivity code??. set text in OnCreate() method using value stored in Shared Preference and also check whether you are able to retrieve values stored in shared preference